# Multiple queries (if conditions) in the best performing way

Tags: mysql

I would like to create a simple licensing system. Upon the very first authentication with a valid license key I need to set a "start date". Every key has a specified validity (for example 30 days). So once the `start_date` is set to the current timestamp I also have to set the `end_date` which is `start_date += length` .

Of course it is possible that someone authenticates with a key which has start_date and end_date already set. This means I have to check with a if-condition whether I need to set `start_date` and `end_date` and I wonder what would be the smartest / best performing way to do this? I am using MySQL 5.6.

**This is the Table structure:** [image]

**My necessary MySQL checks in pseudo:**

```
if(supplied_key found as key_id){
  if(start_date != null)
{
  if(NOW() >= end_date)) return "ok";
  else return "Time exceeded";
}
else{
 start_date = NOW();
 end_date = start_date + length;
 return "ok";
}
}
else return "Key invalid";
```

Comment: Just in case you're ever looking for the antithesis of performant, read [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/180453/27161)

Comment: I would start by not having you key be a 32 character string.

Comment: My question aimed more towards "Stored Procedures" or not and if Stored Procedures how would I do them ?

Comment: @kentor - so you want us to write the code *for you*?  Typically, you'll get a much better response if you show us what you've attempted to do.

Comment: @MaxVernon ... i prefer "runs like poo"

Comment: There is a `DATE` datatype (also a `DATETIME`); use it, not `INT`.

Comment: When the business logic becomes the least bit complex, do it in application code, not MySQL.  A database is for storing data, not for logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly rid your entire else block in pseudo if you used default values correctly. Also why have start time, wouldn't expire time sound more reasonable? Preset expire time with default value of getdate()+whatever.  I see set operations that are meaningless too. Hope this advice you find helpful. I'm not a mysql developer though.

Comment: I think there is a missunderstanding. Basically I have 100 license keys in this system. Each key has a validity of 30 days. But these 30 days only start when someone actually logged in with this license keys. Thus I can't use default values